# Not Getting In-App Purhcasing CallBack in Fire tablet 10, but in Fire tablet 8 IAP is working fine

Tags: amazon-in-app-purchase

I am creating a flutter plugin to manage amazon IAP purchase, everything is working fine in fire tablet 8, but the same plugin is not working in fire tablet 10 plus (11th generation).
On debuging found that callbacks are not coming in fire tablet 10.

Manifest file

```
<application>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver"
        android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I am running the sdk in sandbox mode only, and also configured the app tester also.
I am using appstore sdk 3.0.4 with minSdkVersion 19
I have tried downgrading the sdk version to 3.0.3 but it did not worked.